# SQL Server 2012 Choose Toolbox items, An error occurred loading this property page

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, toolbox

I am getting this error when I need to add a toolbox item to SQL server 2012. It happens when I click Tools -> Choose Toolbox Items. I'm not sure why, would it have something to do with my access rights?

Not sure if its an appropriate question for SO but I searched around and couldn't find anyone else with this error.

Comment: Does your error message contain the text "sp_configure"?

Comment: No, it quite simply says "An error occurred loading this property page" under the tab "Maintenance Tasks" in the "Choose Toolbox Items" dialogue box.